# How to turn on basic filter using google sheets api and still see all values?

Tags: r, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I managed to write an R function using google sheets api's 'setBasicFilter' that turns on the basic filter on the cell range specified by the user. However, when the user tries to 'Filter by values', no values appear to be selected.

The function seems to work fine in the sense that the green filter arrow (or button at the right side of the cells you are using to filter) turn on in the sheets (tabs) and cell range that I want. What I do not understand is why when I click on it, it appears as if there were no values in the column to filter by. It is completely blank but there is data on the column!

I thought perhaps it was setting a filter on top of a filter and tried using 'clearBasicFilter' first before sending 'setBasicFilter' and it did not work.

I tried writing data to the sheet and then turning on the filter and, vice versa, turning on the filter and then writing the data. Still appears as if there were no values to filter by (although the data is there).

In essence, what I am trying to achieve is, when writing data to a sheet:

1. Remove any basic filter present.
2. Write the data.
3. Turn the filter buttons back on (within the range specified by the user of the function).

Here is what my call looks like:

```
# for each row in the param table create a json body
for(row in nrow(param)){

body <- paste0('{"requests": [
  {
    "setBasicFilter": {
      "filter": {
        "range":{"sheetId": ', param$sheetId,
               ', "startRowIndex": ', param$startRow,
               ', "endRowIndex": ', param$endRow,
               ', "startColumnIndex": ', param$startCol,
               ', "endColumnIndex": ', param$endCol,
               '}}}}]}')
 }
```

Where the param table looks like this (and is created based on the users' inputs to the function:

```
|sheetName |startRow |endRow |startCol |endCol |sheetId     |
|:---------|:--------|:------|:--------|:------|:-----------|
|Sheet1    |1        |0      |0        |11     |someId      |
|Sheet2    |0        |0      |0        |11     |someOtherId |
```

Multiple json bodies are created and then I lapply the call using google's batchUpdate method.

I do not get any errors and the filter turns on where I need it to be. I would like to be able to:

1. Go to the sheet I just turned the filter on
2. Click on the green filter arrow (which will already be in the cell range I specified)
3. And see the list of all possible values I can filter that column by

I am sorry for such a long description. I was trying to be as specific as possible.

Comment: The `setBasicFilter` request in your code features a range, but what about the filter criteria? https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#BasicFilter https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/FilterCriteria I am not familiar with `r`, but it is always useful to test with Try this API to understand either the problem lies inot your request itself or the way you implemented it in you programming language https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for your comment. I was actually able to figure out the issue. I was setting the row range to the start row exclusively. In other words, the range only covered the row where the filter was on, therefore the values from all other rows were left out.

Comment: Makes sense. It is often useful to play with the Try it API before implementing a request into your code.

Comment: @ziganotschka Absolutely! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

After re-visiting my function, I found where the issue was. The fix was to default the endRowIndex to the maximum number of rows allowed by google sheets so that all values would be included in the filter range.

For example, with a modified param table that looks like this:

```
|sheetName |startRow |endRow |startCol |endCol |sheetId     |
|:---------|:--------|:------|:--------|:------|:-----------|
|Sheet1    |1        |40000  |0        |11     |someId      |
|Sheet2    |0        |40000  |0        |18278  |someOtherId |
```

And a json body that looks like this:

```
# for each row in the param table create a json body
for(row in nrow(param)){

body <- paste0('{"requests": [
  {
    "setBasicFilter": {
      "filter": {
        "range":{"sheetId": ', param$sheetId,
               ', "startRowIndex": ', param$startRow,
               ', "endRowIndex": ', param$endRow,
               ', "startColumnIndex": ', param$startCol,
               ', "endColumnIndex": ', param$endCol,
               '}}}}]}')
 }
```

The filter will be turned on from A2 to J2 in Sheet1 (all rows included) and A1 to the last column allowed by google sheets (all rows included). I still want the user to be able to specify the end row so I will leave that as an option. An alternative would be to exclude the end row and column indexed in the json body as such:

```
body <- paste0('{"requests": [
     {
        "setBasicFilter": {
          "filter": {
            "range":{"sheetId": ', param$sheetId,
                  ', "startRowIndex": ', param$startRow,
                   ', "startColumnIndex": ', param$startCol
                   '}}}}]}')
     }
```